# Laravel 5 set up on LAMP stack, can't get welcome page to display

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-5, lamp

After installation of Laravel 5 on Ubuntu LAMP stack, I created a virtual host (/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.conf) which looks like:

```
VirtualHost *:80
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName laravelproject
   DocumentRoot /var/www/laravelproject
/VirtualHost
```

(except I actually have VirtualHost between the open < and close >,

I just couldn't get it to display that part with them here. Will play around with it.)
ran a2ensite which enabled the site, updated **/etc/hosts** with

```
127.0.0.1 laravelproject
```

and chmod -R 777 storage/ folder

so when I go to laravelproject/ it displays the file structure of laravelproject. From there, when I click on the public/ folder it prints out the /public/view.php in raw text. And the only way to get the welcome page to display is by navigating manually going into /resources/views/welcome.blade.php

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Basically, I need help to display the Laravel welcome on laravelproject/

I apologize for any incorrect verbage and appreciate any help. I will be happy clarify anything that's unclear. New to web development and stackoverflow. Thank you.

Comment: did you restart your server after making these changes ?

Comment: "it prints out the /public/view.php in raw text" - Sounds like PHP is not installed. Please provide more details on your environment. Did you create a virtual machine? Are you running this on your dev machine? Is it hosted somewhere?

Comment: @KhanShahrukh, I did restart my server after making the changes.

Comment: @Kryten, I am using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu 14.04, it's not hosted anywhere just trying to run it locally right now.

Comment: php -v shows that I have version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13

Answer (score 0):

You should point your apache to the public folder. So modify the `DocumentRoot`Setting inside your `VirtualHost` configuration like so:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/laravelproject/public
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution to my problem here 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2

Apparently, in apache2.4.7, the root directory was changed to /var/www/html for security reasons. So I just had to change DocumentRoot from
/var/www/laravelproject 
to 
/var/www/html/laravelproject/public 
Thanks for the help all :)